# Ridge regression in multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution, ridge-regression, overfitting

When implementing GMM (Gaussian Mixture Model) in practice, the covariance matrix ${\Sigma}_{D\times D}$ is often singular. The reason is that we have to estimate $\frac{D(D+1)}{2}$ parameters in $\Sigma$, which often causes overfitting.

The common solution is adding $\lambda I$ to $\widehat{\Sigma}$ (i.e.$\widehat{\Sigma}=\frac{1}{n}{\Sigma}_{i=1}^{n}((x_i-\mu)(x_i-\mu)^T)+\lambda I$), which comes from ridge regression. However, **I failed to deduce ridge regression in estimation of covariance matrix of multivariate Gaussian distribution**

I have tried below:

For linear models, we introduce least square function to estimate parameters, in case of overfitting (i.e. matrix singular), we adding constraint of $w$ (use its $l_{2}$ norm) :

$f(w)=\frac{1}{2}(Y-Xw)(Y-Xw)^T+\frac{\lambda}{2}w^Tw$

taking derivation of $w$ on both sides, we get $\widehat{w}=(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY$

However, for multivariate Gaussian distribution, we use MLE(maximum likelihood estimation) to estimate parameters. The cost function is the log-maximum likelihood:

$lnP(X,Y|\Sigma,\mu)= \frac{n}{2}ln|{\Sigma}^{-1}|-\frac{1}{2}{\Sigma}_{i=1}^{n}((x_i-\mu)^T{\Sigma}^{-1}(x_i-\mu))+Garbage$

($Garbage$ doesn't contain $\Sigma$)

Follow the constraint of $w$ in linear models, I add constraint of $\Sigma$, which **I assumes to be** $\frac{1}{2}tr(\Sigma ^T\Sigma)$, then the MLE becomes:

$lnP(X,Y|\Sigma,\mu)= \frac{n}{2}ln|{\Sigma}^{-1}|-\frac{1}{2}{\Sigma}_{i=1}^{n}((x_i-\mu)^T{\Sigma}^{-1}(x_i-\mu))+\frac{1}{2}tr(\Sigma ^T\Sigma)+Garbage$

However, after taking derivation of $\Sigma ^{-1}$ on both sides, I failed to get the expected form of $\widehat{\Sigma}=\frac{1}{n}{\Sigma}_{i=1}^{n}((x_i-\mu)(x_i-\mu)^T)+\lambda I$

Could someone give me some help?

Answer (score 1):

It is beyond my current knowledge to present a detailed answer. However, I hope that the following resources will help you figure out the solution. Check [this set of presentation slides](http://www.columbia.edu/~jwp2128/Teaching/W4721/slides/lecture_1-29-15.pdf). Take a look at page 9 of [this document](http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/pdf/TESTOP_1980_31_00_14.pdf): see references to Thisted (1976) and to Brown and Zidek (1980) before equation 18. Finally, [this more recent document](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aos/1123250228) on ridge regression might provide additional ideas.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've read the slides in detail and I found that Gaussian Distributions mentioned in the slides refers to the distribution of the error of linear model (i.e. $e=Y-Xw$ is the Gaussian noise). It is different in GMM that we assume data points are pre-sampled from potential Gaussian Distributions. However, the slides provide a probabilistic view of ridge regression, which is very interesting. I'll read the other two documents you provide and see if they can help. Many thanks!

Comment: @zodiac: You're very welcome! Thank you for the kind words. I'm glad that you found my answer helpful. I'm quite impressed with your mastery of math - the question is nicely formulated (+1).